# c# lock does not work (?)

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have the following locking scenario which seems to miss a lock once in a while, letting 2 code instances to run in parallel. Would appreciate your help in analyzing/fixing the code.

```
public delegate void _D(A a);      

namespace ExternalDll {
    public event _D D;
}

namespace MainSpace {
    ExternalDll _externalDll;
    public static object lockObj = new object();
    public static int counter = 0;
    .
    .
    _externalDll.D += new _D(myEventHandler);
    .
    .
    void myEventHandler(A a) {
        lock (lockObj) {
            counter++;
            // do staff, printouts, etc.
            Console.WriteLine("First={0}\n", counter);
            // do other staff
            Console.WriteLine("Second={0}\n", counter);
        }
    }
}
```

ExternalDll is a dll file that receives network communication with information a (of type A). It calls the event D with a as input.

The main namespace registers myEventHandler to the event D fired by ExternalDll.
Inside myEventHanlder there is a lock, so the expected behavior is that the code inside the lock section is not executed more than once at any time.

However, when running the application, it sometimes reaches a situation that the locked code is executed twice "in parallel". For example, I might see printouts like:

```
First=0
First=1
Second=0
Second=1
```

This happens especially in cases of bursty network events that arrive within a very short time duration (<1us) to the externalDll.

My questions/requests are:

- What could make the lock statement this faulty behavior. allowing 2 instances of the locked code ?
- how to improve the code so that it gives the desired locking behavior.

Thanks,

-Moshe.

Comment: it's locking the variable `theLock` but I see no value assigned to it, didn't you want it to lock `lockObj`?

Comment: Is there other code writing to counter?

Comment: What prospector said above, your sample code uses "theLock" but implies it should be using "lockObj". Maybe clean up your example a bit? Besides that, does "// do other staff" invoke anything that would result in another callback before the event handler completes?

Comment: That was a typo... Edited the code. Thanks

Comment: There is no other code writing to counter. Only the increment shown.   The "do staff" section is pure computation. It does not invoke anything that would result in another callback.

Comment: Lock guarantee that multiple threads will not enter the same block of code, but in your case it is likely code runs in the same thread by firing another event while you are handling previous one

Answer (score 0):

Don't know enough to say. A guess would be two app domains are being created because you are using something that spawns multiple app domains e.g. Asp.net sometimes does this for http modules.

Comment: Yeah, very likely that the OP starts his application numerous times.

Comment: My application is plain compute, not web server or something alike. I see only a single console window while it is running.

Comment: Maybe print the address of lockObj as well to see - could be the marshaller doing something weird.

Comment: Ammm... how do I print that address?   printing the value of  (int)&lockObj gives compile error CS0208 ("Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type 'object'")...  (even in unsafe context)

Comment: Pin the object to get a GCHanndle: https://dzone.com/articles/net-memory-control-use-gchandl then there's a method on GCHandle. As a cheat I sometimes use the hashcode on Object as that mostly differs between objects but is not guaranteed unique.

Comment: I managed to print the address of lockObj. Also printed threadId. Indeed it seems that 2 parallel threads are running, each with its own lockObj...  However I dont see any reason for this to happen. I dont create threads in my code...  Any way to work this out? Or force single thread execution? Is this something related to the registration to the delegate of the external dll??

Comment: In that case, use a [Mutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx) - example on that page - as this is a MarshalByObjRef class which will avoid the problem you are getting into (which I still maintain is akin to multiple app domains probably due to marshalling of a by value class implicitly bound to your event handler).